# Update a Mapbox layer by zoom level when loading geojson

Tags: r, geojson, mapbox, choropleth

Very similar to [this](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/updating-choropleth/) tutorial, I would like to create a MapBox map that at a zoomed out level shows regions (labelled Pcode in my data), but once zoomed it switched to a district level (labelled Name). Ideally both these layers would be part of a single geojson shapefile though  that can be loaded from an external source (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Laurent-Smeets-GSS-Account/geojsons/main/geojsons_files/Districts_261_simplified.json). my questions are

1. how can I format the geojson in such a way that is possible (in R)?
2. how do I load the data into Mapbox to make it switch at a certain zoom level?

I am using [this example](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/polygon-popup-on-click/) on how to load the code

```
    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'MY TOKEN';
    // Create a new map.
    const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map',
        // Choose from Mapbox's core styles, or make your own style with Mapbox Studio
        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v12',
        center: [-100.04, 38.907],
        zoom: 3
    });

    map.on('load', () => {
        // Add a source for the state polygons.
        map.addSource('states', {
            'type': 'geojson',
            'data': 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Laurent-Smeets-GSS-Account/geojsons/main/geojsons_files/Districts_261_simplified.json'
        });

        // Add a layer showing the state polygons.
        map.addLayer({
            'id': 'states-layer',
            'type': 'fill',
            'source': 'states',
            'paint': {
                'fill-color': 'rgba(200, 100, 240, 0.4)',
                'fill-outline-color': 'rgba(200, 100, 240, 1)'
            }
        });

        // When a click event occurs on a feature in the states layer,
        // open a popup at the location of the click, with description
        // HTML from the click event's properties.
        map.on('click', 'states-layer', (e) => {
            new mapboxgl.Popup()
                .setLngLat(e.lngLat)
                .setHTML(e.features[0].properties.Name)
                .addTo(map);
        });

        // Change the cursor to a pointer when
        // the mouse is over the states layer.
        map.on('mouseenter', 'states-layer', () => {
            map.getCanvas().style.cursor = 'pointer';
        });

        // Change the cursor back to a pointer
        // when it leaves the states layer.
        map.on('mouseleave', 'states-layer', () => {
            map.getCanvas().style.cursor = '';
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you would need to flatten your data into single-geometry features as one feature has multi-geometry. Then you can dissolve your data into a second `Feature Collection` based on the propertyName Pcode.
Therefore you can use the dissolve function from [`turf`](https://turfjs.org/docs/#dissolve) - this can be done directly in the browser (I am not aware of how to do it in `R`).
Both geojsons will become a `source` in your `mapboxgl` config.

Based on those sources you create three "sub-layers" for fill, border and symbol (in mapboxgl every property has its own layer).

So in the end you will have 6 sub-layers where 3 represent your "Pcode" data and the other 3 represent the more granular ones.

For hiding / showing the different layer the `maxzoom` and `minzoom` properties on the layers are used.

Working [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fh6mw3r0/).

```js
(async () => {

  // fetch data
  const data = await fetch("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Laurent-Smeets-GSS-Account/geojsons/main/geojsons_files/Districts_261_simplified.json").then(res => res.json());

  // Flat data because we have multi polygons
  const simpleData = turf.flatten(data);

  // Dissolve pCode Data
  const pCodeData = turf.dissolve(simpleData, {
    propertyName: 'Pcode'
  });

  // Init MapboxGL
  mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoicmNvY29ubm9yIiwiYSI6ImNrMDVjZWhyZTA5aDQzaG4wc29ra2F3eHYifQ.icA8-NotLlzhryFxFLvVtQ';
  const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map', // container ID
    // Choose from Mapbox's core styles, or make your own style with Mapbox Studio
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/satellite-v9', // style URL
    projection: 'globe', // Display the map as a globe, since satellite-v9 defaults to Mercator
    zoom: 5, // starting zoom
    center: [0, 10] // // starting center in [lng, lat]
  });


  map.on('load', () => {

    // Switch between layers at this zoomlevel
    const zoomLevelSwitch = 7;

    // Add sources
    map.addSource('simpleData', {
      type: 'geojson',
      data: simpleData
    });

    map.addSource('pCodeData', {
      type: 'geojson',
      data: pCodeData
    });

    // pCodeData
    map.addLayer({
      'id': 'pCodeDataFill',
      'type': 'fill',
      'source': 'pCodeData',
      'layout': {},
      'paint': {
        'fill-color': '#138421'
      },
      maxzoom: zoomLevelSwitch
    });
    map.addLayer({
      'id': 'pCodeDataOutline',
      'type': 'line',
      'source': 'pCodeData',
      'layout': {},
      'paint': {
        'line-color': '#5dea6b',
        'line-width': 2
      },
      maxzoom: zoomLevelSwitch
    });
    map.addLayer({
      'id': 'pCodeDataSymbol',
      'type': 'symbol',
      'source': 'pCodeData',
      'layout': {
        'text-field': ['get', 'Pcode'],
        'text-font': [
          'Open Sans Semibold',
          'Arial Unicode MS Bold'
        ],
        'text-anchor': 'center'
      },
      maxzoom: zoomLevelSwitch
    });

    // Simple Data
    map.addLayer({
      'id': 'simpleDataFill',
      'type': 'fill',
      'source': 'simpleData',
      'layout': {},
      'paint': {
        'fill-color': '#627BC1'
      },
      minzoom: zoomLevelSwitch
    });
    map.addLayer({
      'id': 'simpleDataOutline',
      'type': 'line',
      'source': 'simpleData',
      'layout': {},
      'paint': {
        'line-color': '#09b5f9',
        'line-width': 2
      },
      minzoom: zoomLevelSwitch
    });
    map.addLayer({
      'id': 'simpleDataSymbol',
      'type': 'symbol',
      'source': 'simpleData',
      'layout': {
        'text-field': ['get', 'Name'],
        'text-font': [
          'Open Sans Semibold',
          'Arial Unicode MS Bold'
        ],
        'text-anchor': 'center'
      },
      minzoom: zoomLevelSwitch
    });
  })
})()
```